# Can't access Application Helper method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a method that checks for a boolean value on a table, and it returns false in my Users views (everywhere else it returns true). I am having trouble understanding why it is accessible, but returns false.

My code:

Application Controller:

```
protected

def current_user

  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session_user_id) if session_user_id
end

helper_method :current_user

def current_customer
  if current_user.customer and current_user.customer.master?
  else
    current_user.customer
  end
end

helper_method :current_customer
```

Application helper method:

```
def customer_helper?
   (current_user && current_user.customer.boolean_value?) 
end
```

the customer_helper? method returns false in all of my Users views, even though my UsersController inherits from ApplicationController.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `customer_helper?` method defined?

Comment: In application_helper.rb

Comment: `current_customer` will return `nil` if `current_user.customer && current_user.customer.master?` evaluates to true. I think that is you issue.

Comment: I just used binding.pry and you're right, NoMethodError: undefined method `customer' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):27:in `boolean_value?'  Does this mean that current_user.customer.master? can't access the boolean_value column?

Comment: Please explain you intentions because there are probably easier ways to handle this. right now your error is that `current_user` is nil thus no `customer` method. I pointed out that you have not return in `current_customer` but I think you need to relook at the code to determine why `current_user` is `nil` first.

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is `nil` within the helper method.  I assume you are accessing this in a view where current_user has been exposed to the view from the controller.  The attributes exposed to the view must be passed into the helper methods; they are are not automatically made available there.

If my assumptions are correct then your helper method should look something like this.

```
def customer_helper?(current_user)
  (current_user && current_user.customer.boolean_value?) 
end
```

You will then need to update the call to `customer_helper?` in your view to pass in the current_user.